# Write a function called randomization that takes as input a positive integer n, and returns A, a random n x 1 Numpy array

Tags: python, function, numpy, random, integer

Write a function called randomization that takes as input a positive integer n, and returns A, a random n x 1 numpy array.

Below is what I have but it's not working.

```py
import numpy as np

def randomization(n):
    if n>0 and n==int:
        A=np.random.random([n, 1])
    print(A)
x=int(input("enter a positive number: "))
r=randomization(x)
print(r)
```

If I run this I get a message saying "local variable 'A' referenced before assignment".

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what chepner said, np.random.rand expects dimensions as arguments and not a list. That is, you should use A=np.random.rand(n, 1). Note that this returns a uniformly distributed random vector.
Also, your function doesn't return any value. use - return A at the end.

Comment: So I applied your comments, but still it doesnt run properly...

import numpy as np
def randomization(n):
    while (n > 0) and isinstance(n, int):
        A = np.random.rand(n, 1)
    return A
x = int(input("enter a positive integer number: "))
r = randomization(x)
print(r)

you mean i wld need to change that print(r) -> return A?

Comment: This should work:
    import numpy as np
    def randomization(n):
        if n>0 and type(n)==int:
            A=np.random.rand(n, 1)
            print(A)
            return A
    x=int(input("enter a positive number: "))
    r=randomization(x)
    print(r)

Answer (score 2):

First, `n == int` will always be false, because `n` is not the type `int`. Use `isinstance(n, int)` instead.

Because of that, `A` is never assigned, but then you call `print(A)` as if it *were* assigned.

Comment: So I applied your comments, but still it doesnt run properly...

import numpy as np
def randomization(n):
    while (n > 0) and isinstance(n, int):
        A = np.random.rand(n, 1)
    return A
x = int(input("enter a positive integer number: "))
r = randomization(x)
print(r)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this. You must define your function, set A equal to a random matrix nx1 and then return the value A within you definition.

```
      A = np.random.random([n,1])
      return A
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Q) Write a function called randomization that takes as input a positive integer n, and returns A, a random n x 1 numpy array.----

Ans)
def randomization(n):
random_array=np.random.random([n,1])
return random_array
a=randomization(4)
print(a)

Comment: Please enter code sample as text formatted as code so it can be read easily

Answer (score -1):

try using this. Please make sure your indentation is correct:

```
def operations(h,w):
    """
    Takes two inputs, h and w, and makes two Numpy arrays A and B of size
    h x w, and returns A, B, and s, the sum of A and B.
    Arg:
      h - an integer describing the height of A and B
      w - an integer describing the width of A and B
    Returns (in this order):
      A - a randomly-generated h x w Numpy array.
      B - a randomly-generated h x w Numpy array.
      s - the sum of A and B.
    """
    A = np.random.random([h,w])
    B = np.random.random([h,w])
    s = A + B
    return A,B,s
A,B,s = operations(3,4)
assert(A.shape == B.shape == s.shape)*
```